# Rounded edges are not smooth(using drawRoundRectangle in android)

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm using drawRoundRect function in Canvas to draw a round edged rectangle. when the x and y radius is small like 3, the curve seems to be smooth. But when i increase the radius upto 20 the edges are not smooth and it doesnt looks fine. Can someone help me?

I'm having the following code in my constructor

```
 paint= new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED); // set default color to white 
            Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.texture);   
            Rect tempRect = new Rect(0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight());
            Bitmap tile = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, tempRect.left,
                    tempRect.top, tempRect.right - tempRect.left,
                    tempRect.bottom - tempRect.top);
            BitmapShader bs = new BitmapShader(tile, TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
            paint.setShader(bs);
            rect=new RectF(20,20,600,200);
```

and in onDraw i'm calling

```
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 20, 20, paint);
```

Comment: Set `antiAliasing` to true for paint object

Comment: Show me the code here it is usfull to help you.

Comment: I'm creating the paint object like this
Paint paint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

Answer (score 0):

To draw smooth corners use anti-aliasing..

```
final Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(color);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
```

then use

```
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 20, 20, paint);
```

Comment: Tried using that. Still the curve is not smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old. However, the problem is re-draw.
Because of how anti-aliasing works, if you redraw a shape without clearing the bitmap first. It was result in rough edges. I've covered this in more detail [here](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/android-why-your-canvas-shapes-arent-smooth-aa2a3f450eb5#.kill8q45y).